# Queueing and Handling multiple requests on iphone

Tags: iphone

In my application, I'm using NSOperationQueue and NSInvocationOperation objects to execute all the operations. I have multiple queues in my application and I am using KVO "isFinished" on call of which I am performing the next operation on main thread.

The problem is: whenever I perform two operations one after another my application crashes saying:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<myViewController: 0x481b200>: An     -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
Key path: isFinished
Observed object: <NSInvocationOperation: 0x45d9ea0>
Change: {
 kind = 1;
}
Context: 0x0'
```

My general code is as follows:

```
operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(somemethod) object:nil];

[operation addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isFinished" options:0 context:nil];

[operationQueue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];    

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                        ofObject:(id)object 
                           change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                         context:(void *)context
{
   if([keyPath isEqual:@"isFinished"] && operation == object)
 {


    [operation removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isFinished"];
     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(newerPostLoadingNumberOfUdates) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

 } 


 else 
 {
     [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
 }
}
```

I want to know wheather what is the best practice to enqueue operations that are requested and execute them accordingly?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: I noticed some suspicious string comparing. I think that is safer to use isEqualToString: instead of isEqual:. Anyway my practise when working with operation queues is to add one extra empty operation to queue that will be marker when previously added operation has finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be difficult to answer w/o seeing more of your code as you mention using multiple queues. I see a few things to consider:

1) you have `[operation release]` and then you compare `operation` to `object` in your KVO handler. you should not release `operation until you are done with it. In the KVO handler in this case.

2) as mentioned above, you should do string compares using `isEqualToString`

3) it sounds like you are trying to run your queue sequentially such that only one operation is executed at a time and you queue another operation after the first has finished. Instead you could set your queue to only perform one operation at a time with:

```
operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
```

and then add all the operations at once. If order of execution matters, you can use Grand Central Dispatch directly and use `dispatch_sync` to execute blocks in a specific sequence on a queue.